# Hadoop 1.2.1 - using Distributed Cache

Tags: java, hadoop, distributed-cache

I have developed a Hadoop application that uses distributed cache. I used Hadoop 2.9.0. Everything works fine in stand-alone and pseudo-distributed mode.

Driver:

```
public class MyApp extends Configured implements Tool{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        if(args.length < 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: Myapp -files cache.txt <inputpath> <outputpath>");

        System.exit(-1);
    }

    int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new IDS(), args);
    System.exit(res);
```

...

Mapper:

```
public class IDSMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable> {
@Override
    protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("cache.txt")));
```

Starting: `sudo bin/hadoop jar MyApp.jar -files cache.txt /input /output`

Now I need to measure execution time on a real Hadoop cluster. Unfortunately, I have Hadoop cluster with Hadoop 1.2.1 version on my disposal. So I created new Eclipse project, referenced appropriate Hadoop 1.2.1 jar files, and evertything works fine in stand-alone mode. However, pseudo-distributed mode with Hadoop 1.2.1 fails with an FileNotFoundException in Mapper class (setup method), when trying to read distributed cache file.

Do I have to handle distributed cache files in some other way in Hadoop 1.2.1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in the run method. I used *Job.getInstance* method without parameters, and I should use it this way:

```
Job job = Job.getInstance(getConf());
```

I still don't know why Hadoop 2.9.0 works with just:

```
Job job = Job.getInstance();
```

but *getConf* solved my problems.